Why is the total delivery count decreasing day by day in Journey Builder email tracking?
I sent an email on 1st April using Journey Builder and the same day report showed that the tracking number of delivered was 29096, the same email the number delivered on 2nd April was 29094 and the number delivered on 8th April was 29033.
Why is the total delivery count decreasing day by day in Journey Builder email tracking?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

You should not rely on "delivered" count the first 72 hours after a send was initiated from SFMC. The reason is, SFMC assumes the email delivered unless a bounce is detected. Since SFMC will attempt to deliver the email for up to 72 hours, it is only at that point that the number will be "fixed".
This article explains in more details bounce handling in SFMC.
